# How to access a range/interval of keys in an ordered map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to write an if-condition where I want to execute code depending on which elements of a map are accessed, e.g. for a map with 100 elements only for elements 26 to 74. But I do not want to address specific keys but rather a certain fraction of the map. Should I do this with the `[]` operator? I tried

```
if(map.size()/4 < iterator < map.size()*3/4){}
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get iterators to the beginning and end of the range you want to inspect like

```
auto it = std::next(map.begin(), map.size() / 4);
auto end = std::next(map.begin(), map.size() * 3 / 4);
```

and then you can iterate that range like

```
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

You don't even need the end iterator if you want to you a counter.  This saves you the cost of advancing the end iterator through the map which could make a difference, especially on larger maps.  That would look like

```
auto it = std::next(map.begin(), map.size() / 4);
auto end = map.size() / 2;
for (size_t counter = 0; counter < end; ++it, ++counter)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I'd consider it worth a mention that creating the iterators is linear in the size of the map. It's probably premature optimization to therefore advance from `it` by half the map size to get `end` instead (or going backwards from the end - although that would be more symmetric), but ymmv.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat idea, using the iterators. I suppose defining more iterators is the most efficient approach for working on subsets of a map? Meaning instead of creating multiple maps? The map itself is created using a pointer to a list.

Comment: @fitzy_blarb As long as you aren't mutating the map (adding or removing elements) then I would just work on slices instead of copying it into a new map.  copying is expensive and if could be avoided it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot efficiently get this information from a `std::map` iterator, because they are not random access (but only bidirectional). In other words, given a `std::map` iterator, you can find out how many entries are before and after it only by decrementing/incrementing it until you are at the start/end. If you do this for every entry (e.g. in some `<algorithm>` function), that's risking a performance bottleneck - which may be acceptable in your situation, but you should be aware of it.

If you can do what NathanOliver suggests, that's great, but there are situations where it might not be that easy (e.g. non-contiguous ranges).